# sql not inserting into database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I know this is a pretty common question, but I am just looking for help in identifying what's wrong with my code. I'm attempting to create my database so that an admin can create new campsites with pictures from a form. My website seems to be working alright and when I test it, it gives me the fail message if values are not filled in and success message if required values are not filled in, but it is not passing the information on to my database. Any help would be very appreciated!

Also, I apologize for being a very bad coder.

Relevant website code:

```
<section id="SIGNUP" style="text-align: center;" class="main-container">
        <div class="container" style="width:100%;">
      <h2 style="text-align:center; font-size:50px;">Add a New Campsite</h2>
      <form id="newsletter" <form class="signup-form" action="includes/fetch.inc.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="padding-top:50px; padding-bottom:50px; border-bottom:#e8491d 3px solid; border-top:#e8491d 3px solid;">
        <input type="integer"  name="length" style="padding:4px; height:5%; width:25%; text-align:center; font-size:30px;" placeholder="Site Length"><br>
            <input type="integer" name="width" style="padding:4px; height:5%; width:25%; text-align:center; font-size:30px;" placeholder="Site Width"><br>
            <label for="fire">Fire Pit: </label><input type="checkbox" name="fire" value="No">
            <label for="electric">Electricity: </label><input type="checkbox" name="electric" value="No">
            <label for="sewer">Sewage: </label><input type="checkbox" name="sewer" value="No"></br>
      <input type="decimal" name="price" style="padding:4px; height:5%; width:25%; text-align:center; font-size:30px;" placeholder="Price"><br>
  <input type="file" id="upload_file" name="upload_file[]" onchange="preview_image();" multiple/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit_image" value="Upload Image"/>
 </form>
 <div id="image_preview"></div>
</div>
</section>;
```

fetch.inc.php / sql code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit_image'])) {

  require_once("dbh.inc.php");

    $length = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['length']);
    $width = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['width']);
  $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['price']);
    //Error Handlers
    //Check for empty fields

    if (empty($length) || empty($width) || empty($price)) {
        header("Location: ../admin.php?null-value");
        exit();
  } else {

//insert image address into images folder and add the address to reservations table
    for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["upload_file"]["name"]);$i++)
    {
     $uploadfile=$_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"][$i];
     $folder="images/";
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"][$i], "$folder".$_FILES["upload_file"]["name"][$i]);
    $image = "$folder".$_FILES["upload_file"]["name"];


    $sql = "INSERT INTO campsites (length, width, fire, sewer, electric, price)
    VALUES ('$length', '$width', '$fire', '$sewer', '$electric', '$price');";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    header("Location: ../admin.php?signup=Success");
    exit();

// Transform checkbox values into binary sql values

        if (isset($_POST['fire']) && ($_POST['fire'] == "value")) {
            $fire .= "1";
        } else {
            $fire .= "0";
        }

    if (isset($_POST['sewer']) && ($_POST['sewer'] == "value")) {
      $sewer .= "1";
    } else {
      $sewer .= "0";
    }

    if (isset($_POST['electric']) && ($_POST['electric'] == "value")) {
      $electric .= "1";
    } else {
      $electric .= "0";
    }
  }
}

}
exit();
?>
```

Comment: _"but it is not passing the information on to my database"_, are you sure that it reaches the line that inserts into the database?If yes, do you receive any warning?

Comment: There are only two messages that I get.
1: when I don't have the required values, I get the "Location: ../admin.php?null-value" header
2: When I do have the required values, I get the ""Location: ../admin.php?signup=Success" header 

The actual fetch.ini.php page returns nothing

Comment: the values of the fields `fire`,`sewer` and `electric` are, by default `'No'` so how are they to equal `'value'`?

Comment: Honestly, it's probably just bad coding that I picked up from the internet and hoped would work. My thought process is that the value while no is 0 and the value while checked is 1 and can be more easily inserted into the database. I hope that's correct anyways!

Comment: There is an error in the html form `<form id="newsletter" <form class=` should be `<form id="newsletter" class=`

Comment: Shouldnt this part  be before the insert: // Transform checkbox values into binary sql values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you edit the field values for `fire`,`sewer` and `electric` by changing them to integers with a default value of `1` ( one) you will simplify some of the logic in php.

The `insert` statements ought really to use `prepared statements` to avoid sql injection.

I'd also strongly  suggest that you use `css` to control the look of the form rather than the inline styles you have here - it makes the code leaner, easier to read and more importantly easier to change!

The code below is all on one page for me to test - you'll need to split the html and php into the two constituent pages as you originally had them ~ sorry for changing it around so much but I think you should be able to get it working now from this.

```
<?php

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['length'], $_POST['width'], $_POST['price'] ) ){
        try{

            require_once("dbh.inc.php");

            function uploaderror( $code ){ 
                switch( $code ) { 
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE: return "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini"; 
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE: return "The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form"; 
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL: return "The uploaded file was only partially uploaded"; 
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE: return "No file was uploaded"; 
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR: return "Missing a temporary folder"; 
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE: return "Failed to write file to disk"; 
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION: return "File upload stopped by extension"; 
                    default: return "Unknown upload error";
                }
            }

            $filefield='upload_file';
            $status=false;
            $sql = "insert into `campsites` ( `length`, `width`, `fire`, `sewer`, `electric`, `price`) values (?,?,?,?,?,?);";

            $length=filter_input( INPUT_POST,'length',FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
            $width=filter_input( INPUT_POST,'width',FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
            $price=filter_input( INPUT_POST,'price',FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );

            $fire=isset( $_POST['fire'] ) ? filter_input( INPUT_POST,'fire',FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT ) : 0;
            $sewer=isset( $_POST['sewer'] ) ? filter_input( INPUT_POST,'sewer',FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT ) : 0;
            $electric=isset( $_POST['electric'] ) ? filter_input( INPUT_POST,'electric',FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT ) : 0;





            if( !$length or !$width or !$price ){
                exit( header("Location: ../admin.php?null-value") );
            }

            $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
            if( !$stmt ) throw new Exception('Failed to prepare sql statement');

            $stmt->bind_param('iiiiii', $length, $width, $fire, $sewer, $electric, $price );

            if( isset( $_FILES[ $filefield ] ) ){
                foreach( $_FILES[ $filefield ]['name'] as $i => $name ) {
                    if( !empty( $_FILES[ $filefield ]['tmp_name'][$i] ) ) {

                        $name = $_FILES[ $filefield ]['name'][$i];
                        $size = $_FILES[ $filefield ]['size'][$i];
                        $type = $_FILES[ $filefield ]['type'][$i];
                        $tmp  = $_FILES[ $filefield ]['tmp_name'][$i];
                        $err  = $_FILES[ $filefield ]['error'][$i];

                        $target="images/{$name}";
                        #$target='c:/temp/fileuploads/1/'.$name;

                        if( is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) ){
                            $bytes = move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $target );
                        } else {
                            throw new Exception( sprintf('Error: %s',uploaderror( $err ) ) );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $result = $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();

            exit( header( "Location: ../admin.php?signup=$result" ) );

        }catch( Exception $e ){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="SIGNUP" class="main-container">
            <div class="container">
                <h2>Add a New Campsite</h2>

                <form class="signup-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <input type="number"  name="length" placeholder="Site Length"><br>
                    <input type="number" name="width" placeholder="Site Width"><br>

                    <label for="fire">Fire Pit: </label><input type="checkbox" name="fire" value=1>
                    <label for="electric">Electricity: </label><input type="checkbox" name="electric" value=1>
                    <label for="sewer">Sewage: </label><input type="checkbox" name="sewer" value=1></br>

                    <input type="number" name="price" placeholder="Price"><br>
                    <input type="file" id="upload_file" name="upload_file[]" onchange="preview_image();" multiple/>

                    <input type="submit" name="submit_image" value="Upload Images & Save"/>
                </form>
                <div id="image_preview"></div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

I had a bit of a play about after I made that last comment regarding storing a reference to the images being stored in the database - perhaps it may be of interest.

No doubt the actual database schema is far more complicated but I quickly built 2 tables for the demo.

```
create table `campsites` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
    `length` smallint(5) unsigned not null default '0',
    `width` smallint(5) unsigned not null default '0',
    `fire` bit(1) not null default b'0',
    `sewer` bit(1) not null default b'0',
    `electric` bit(1) not null default b'0',
    `price` decimal(10,0) unsigned not null default '0',
    primary key (`id`)
)
collate='utf8_general_ci'
engine=innodb;

create table `campsite_images` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
    `cid` int(10) unsigned not null default '0',
    `photo` varchar(128) not null default '0',
    primary key (`id`),
    index `cid` (`cid`),
    constraint `fk_cs_img` foreign key (`cid`) references `campsites` (`id`) on update cascade on delete cascade
)
collate='utf8_general_ci'
engine=innodb;



mysql> describe campsites;
+----------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type                   | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(10) unsigned       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| length   | smallint(5) unsigned   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| width    | smallint(5) unsigned   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| fire     | bit(1)                 | NO   |     | b'0'    |                |
| sewer    | bit(1)                 | NO   |     | b'0'    |                |
| electric | bit(1)                 | NO   |     | b'0'    |                |
| price    | decimal(10,0) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+----------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


mysql> describe campsite_images;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| cid   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| photo | varchar(128)     | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And modified the above code

```
<?php

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['length'], $_POST['width'], $_POST['price'] ) ){
        try{
            $redirect=false;
            $message=false;
            $filefield='upload_file';
            $status=false;
            $imgdir='c:/temp/fileuploads/1/';
            $results=array();

            #require_once("dbh.inc.php");

            $dbhost =   'localhost';
            $dbuser =   'root'; 
            $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
            $dbname =   'xxx';
            $conn   =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );




            function uploaderror( $code ){ 
                switch( $code ) { 
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE: return "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini"; 
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE: return "The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form"; 
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL: return "The uploaded file was only partially uploaded"; 
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE: return "No file was uploaded"; 
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR: return "Missing a temporary folder"; 
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE: return "Failed to write file to disk"; 
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION: return "File upload stopped by extension"; 
                    default: return "Unknown upload error";
                }
            }



            $sql = "insert into `campsites` ( `length`, `width`, `fire`, `sewer`, `electric`, `price`) values (?,?,?,?,?,?);";
            $sql_image = 'insert into `campsite_images` (`cid`,`photo`) values (?,?)';

            $length=filter_var( filter_input( INPUT_POST,'length',FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT ), FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT );
            $width=filter_var( filter_input( INPUT_POST,'width',FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT ), FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT );
            $price=filter_var( filter_input( INPUT_POST,'price',FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT ), FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT );

            $fire=isset( $_POST['fire'] ) ? filter_input( INPUT_POST,'fire',FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT ) : 0;
            $sewer=isset( $_POST['sewer'] ) ? filter_input( INPUT_POST,'sewer',FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT ) : 0;
            $electric=isset( $_POST['electric'] ) ? filter_input( INPUT_POST,'electric',FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT ) : 0;





            if( !$length or !$width or !$price ){
                if( $redirect ) exit( header( "Location: ../admin.php?null-value" ) );
            }
            if( !is_numeric( $length ) or !is_numeric( $width ) or !is_numeric( $price ) ){
                throw new Exception('Non-Float values for length, width and price are not allowed.');
            }

            $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
            if( !$stmt ) throw new Exception('Failed to prepare sql statement');
            $stmt->bind_param('iiiiii', $length, $width, $fire, $sewer, $electric, $price );


            $stmt_image=$conn->prepare( $sql_image );
            if( !$stmt_image )throw new Exception('Unable to prepare image sql statement');
            $stmt_image->bind_param('is', $id, $target );


            /* insert record for campsite */
            $results[]=$stmt->execute();

            /* Get the ID for the campsite that was just added */
            $id=$stmt->insert_id;

            /* Process any & all images that are uploaded */
            if( isset( $_FILES[ $filefield ] ) ){
                foreach( $_FILES[ $filefield ]['name'] as $i => $name ) {
                    if( !empty( $_FILES[ $filefield ]['tmp_name'][$i] ) ) {

                        $name = $_FILES[ $filefield ]['name'][$i];
                        $size = $_FILES[ $filefield ]['size'][$i];
                        $type = $_FILES[ $filefield ]['type'][$i];
                        $tmp  = $_FILES[ $filefield ]['tmp_name'][$i];
                        $err  = $_FILES[ $filefield ]['error'][$i];

                        $target = $imgdir . $name;

                        if( is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) ){
                            $bytes = move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $target );
                            $results[]=$stmt_image->execute();
                        } else {
                            throw new Exception( sprintf('Error: %s', uploaderror( $err ) ) );
                        }
                    }
                }
                $stmt_image->close();
            }

            $result=new stdClass;
            $result->failed=0;
            $result->success=0;

            array_walk( $results, function($value){
                global $result;
                if( $value==0 )$result->failed++;
                if( $value==1 )$result->success++;
            });

            $message=sprintf( 'Record(s) added - Failed:%d, Success:%d', $result->failed, $result->success );

            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();



            if( $redirect ) exit( header( "Location: ../admin.php?signup=true" ) );

        }catch( Exception $e ){
            $message=$e->getMessage();
        }
    }

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Campsite booking form</title>
        <style>
            html,html *{
                font-family:calibri,verdana,arial;
                box-sizing:border-box;
            }
            #signup{
                text-align: center;
                width:50%;
                float:none;
                margin:0 auto;
            }
            h2{text-align:center; font-size:4rem;}
            h3{font-size:0.95rem;color:green;}
            input{padding:1rem;}

            input[type='text'],
            input[type='number']{
                float:none;
                width:calc(33% - 1rem );
                margin:0.5rem auto;
            }
            fieldset{
                width:90%;
                border:none;
                margin:1rem auto;
                float:none;
            }
            input[type='file']{
                width: 0.1px;
                height: 0.1px;
                opacity: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
                position: absolute;
                z-index: -1;
            }
            input[type='file'] + label{
                font-weight: 700;
                color: black;
                background-color: #E5E4E2;
                display: inline-block;
                border:1px solid black;
                padding:0.25rem;
                width:90%;
                cursor:pointer;
                float:none;
                margin:0 auto;
            }


            label[for='upload_file']:hover {
                background: rgba(240,182,198,0.75)!important;
            }

            input[type='submit']{
                width:90%;
                float:none;
                margin:1rem auto;
            }
            #services label{
                padding:1rem;
                display:inline-block;
                clear:none;
                float:none;
                margin:0 auto;
                width:calc(33% - 5px);!important;
            }
            ul#list{font-size:0.7rem;}
            #image_preview img{margin:0.25rem;padding:0.25rem;outline:1px dotted gray;}
        </style>
        <script>
            /* self-executing anonymous function */
            (function(){

                var getaspect=function(w,h){
                    w=parseFloat(w);
                    h=parseFloat(h);
                    if( w==h )return 1;
                    else if( w > h ) return 2;
                    else if( h > w ) return 3;
                    else return 4;
                }
                var getratio=function(w,h){
                    return parseFloat(w) / parseFloat(h);
                }
                var roundNumber=function(i,p){
                    return Math.floor( i * Math.pow( 10, p ) ) / Math.pow( 10, p );
                };
                var getfilesize=function(i){
                    var kb=1024;
                    var mb=Math.pow(kb,2);
                    var gb=Math.pow(kb,3);
                    var tb=Math.pow(kb,4);

                    if( i > 0 && i < kb ) return i+'bytes';
                    else if( i >= kb && i < mb ) return roundNumber( Math.abs( i / kb ),2 ) + 'Kb';
                    else if( i >= mb && i < gb ) return roundNumber( Math.abs( i / mb ),2 ) + 'Mb';
                    else if( i >= gb && i < tb ) return roundNumber( Math.abs( i / gb ),2 ) + 'Gb';
                    else if( i >= tb ) return roundNumber( Math.abs( i / tb ),2 ) + 'Tb';
                };

                var size=150;
                var options={
                    capture:false,
                    once:false,
                    passive:true
                };
                document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(e){

                    var oImages=[];
                    var oInput=document.getElementById('upload_file');
                    var oPreview=document.getElementById('image_preview');
                    var oList=document.getElementById('list');

                    oInput.addEventListener('change',function(event){
                        var files=this.files;
                        for( var i=0; i < files.length; i++ ){
                            var file=files.item( i );
                            var obj={
                                'file':file,
                                'name':file.name,
                                'size':file.size,
                                'lastModified':file.lastModified,
                                'lastModifiedDate':file.lastModifiedDate,
                                'type':file.type
                            };
                            oImages.push( obj );

                            var li=document.createElement('li');
                                li.dataset.name=obj.name;
                                li.dataset.lastmod=obj.lastModifiedDate;
                                li.dataset.type=obj.type;
                                li.innerHTML=obj.name + ' [ '+getfilesize( obj.size )+' ]';

                            oList.appendChild( li );

                            /********************/
                            /* Show a preview */
                            var img = document.createElement('img');
                                img.file=obj.file;
                                img.dataset.name=obj.name;
                                img.title=obj.name;
                                img.onload=function(event){

                                    var ratio=getratio( this.width,this.height );
                                    switch( getaspect( this.width, this.height ) ){
                                        case 1:
                                            this.width=size;
                                            this.height=size;
                                        break;
                                        case 2:
                                            this.width=size;
                                            this.height=size / ratio;
                                        break;
                                        case 3:
                                            this.height=size;
                                            this.width=size * ratio;
                                        break;
                                        case 4:
                                            alert('error')
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL( this.src );
                                };

                            /* add new thumbnail to the DOM */
                            oPreview.appendChild( img );

                            /* read the file and set the image source */
                            var reader = new FileReader();
                                reader.onload = (function(a) { return function(e) { a.src = e.target.result; }; })( img );
                                reader.readAsDataURL( obj.file );

                        }
                    }.bind( oInput ),options );
                },options );
            })();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id='signup' class='main-container'>
            <div class='container'>
                <h2>Add a New Campsite</h2>
                <?php
                    if( $message ){
                        echo "<h3>$message</h3>";
                    }
                ?>
                <form class='signup-form' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>

                    <fieldset id='dimensions'>
                        <input type='number'  name='length' placeholder='Site Length' step=1 min=1 max=1000 />
                        <input type='number' name='width' placeholder='Site Width' step=1 min=1 max=1000 />
                        <input type='number' name='price' placeholder='Price' step='0.5' min=0 max=1000 />
                    </fieldset>

                    <fieldset id='services'>
                        <label for='fire'>Fire Pit: <input type='checkbox' name='fire' value=1></label>
                        <label for='electric'>Electricity: <input type='checkbox' name='electric' value=1></label>
                        <label for='sewer'>Sewage: <input type='checkbox' name='sewer' value=1></label>
                    </fieldset>

                    <fieldset id='files'>
                        <input type='file' id='upload_file' name='upload_file[]' multiple/>
                        <label for='upload_file' title='Optional: Upload photos'>
                            <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='20' height='17' viewBox='0 0 20 17'>
                                <path d='M10 0l-5.2 4.9h3.3v5.1h3.8v-5.1h3.3l-5.2-4.9zm9.3 11.5l-3.2-2.1h-2l3.4 2.6h-3.5c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.1l-.8 2.3h-6l-.8-2.2c-.1-.1-.1-.2-.2-.2h-3.6l3.4-2.6h-2l-3.2 2.1c-.4.3-.7 1-.6 1.5l.6 3.1c.1.5.7.9 1.2.9h16.3c.6 0 1.1-.4 1.3-.9l.6-3.1c.1-.5-.2-1.2-.7-1.5z'></path>
                            </svg> <span>Choose a file…</span>
                        </label>
                    </fieldset>

                    <fieldset id='bttns'>
                        <input type='submit' name='submit_image' value='Upload Images & Save'/>
                    </fieldset>

                </form>
                <div id='image_preview'></div>
                <ul id='list'></ul>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's still not quite working and giving me the same lack of context as to why it's not working, but I really appreciate what you've given me. I'm going to guess that it's a hell of a lot more functional than the stuff I wrote out.

Also, I completely agree that I am not utilizing best practices. I would also say that I know nothing about best practices and was pushed into a project that's so far out of my depth with so little guidance, that I'll be happy if it's semi-functional

Comment: where does it fail? Do the images get uploaded? Is it the sql that is failing?

Comment: Sorry, I got a little premature with that comment. I've followed your advice and changed the sql values to int instead of bool and then inserted both sets of code that you've provided. I'm sure it's something small that I'm trying to sort out, but I'm getting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ',' or ']' in /storage/ssd2/948/4122948/public_html/includes/fetch.inc.php on line 28"  --- I tried changing the mismatched parenthetical to the bracket, but ended up getting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: There was a missing `]` after `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'` ~ the above code has been edited just now after testing here. Inserts images and inserts record into db ok now.

Comment: This is great! I've been beating my head against the keyboard for almost a week now. I appreciate it!

Comment: I'm glad it helped and happy that [a] the keyboard will be saved [b] you head will no longer be bruised. Good luck with the rest! One question though, why are you not storing references to the images that you upload for the particular record that gets inserted?

Comment: Honestly? Because I don't know what the hell I'm doing. My professor is a great guy, but he threw me into this project after one semester of some basic sql, python, and vb.net. I've watched a couple youtube tutorials and done online research and from there, slapped this monstrosity together lol. Also, I love what you did with the layout. It's simple and I really feel like should have thought of it!

Comment: I noticed a comment below which gives a link to the actual site and found that you have some work to do my friend! There are errors being displayed ( when you visit certain parts of the site ) which really ought not to be displayed. (example: load `/includes/reserve.inc.php` directly in browser ) ~ that said - Happy New Year and ping me back in 2018 if you need advice

Comment: Yeah, reserve.inc.php is actually my next project page as well as my actual campgrounds page. I've got a start on it (obviously), but still a heck of a lot of work left! I really do appreciate all of your help and will probably take you up on that!

Comment: so I'm unsure how to ping you and don't have enough reputation to chat. Is there a way I could contact you with a question (if you're available)?  Also, Happy New Year to you too!

Comment: leaving a comment here creates an alert notification which is enough. Rather than create an extended discussion however ask a new question and then post a comment here

Comment: you're a godsend sir! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054083/php-not-passing-along-variables

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without seeing all the code (e.g. what your `require_once("dbh.inc.php");` is doing) but I'd hazard a guess that an error will be being thrown by PHP and / or MySQL.

To make your code a little more robust add checks to ensure your query was executed correctly:

```
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    error_log("SQL query error: " . mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

Then check your PHP error log, you should see the results in there.

Your error log files will be found by checking your `php.ini` and `mysql.cnf` files. Common default locations if you're using Linux:

```
/var/log/php_errors.log
/var/log/mysqld.log
```

If you're using a hosting provider running something like cPanel, you should find access to your log files in there.

You *could* print the error to screen making it easier to debug but this is **not** recommended in production code for security reasons. Once you're comfortable with accessing your error logs you shouldn't need to do this anyway, but for the record:

```
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    print "Error: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    error_log("SQL query error: " . mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

Comment: I guess it's not the most clear (oops), but dbh.inc.php is my connection to the database. Probably the only thing in this big mess of code that I know will be running correctly!

Comment: Also, I am using 000webhostapp and have no idea how to look into my logs. Hopefully I can find it on the ewbsite!  https://campease.000webhostapp.com/index.php

Comment: Looks like 000webhost.com do use cPanel, that's the web site to log into to control and administer your website. There should be a **Metrics** section, in there you should see an **Errors** section and hopefully in there you'll see the error logs. (Or just display the errors to the screen with the `print "Error: " . mysqli_error($conn);` suggestion above, but remember to take it out after you've finished debugging though! :) )